# genertae XML file of table structure form store procedure

Tags: xml, oracle, stored-procedures, plsqldeveloper

I want to create store procedure for generate a XML file of table structure as per given table name as input parameter

I use below Query

```
 select  
               distinct   column_name,
                  data_type,
                   data_length  
                   from all_tab_columns  
                   where table_name =UPPER('Project')
                   order by column_id;
```

but it shows error
ORA-00904: "PROJECT": invalid identifier
here PROJECT is my table name

I has create a Store procedure but its shows error

```
create or replace 
procedure table_str (
   V_TABLE_NAME IN varchar2,
    v_FLAG OUT NUMBER
)
AS

BEGIN
    DECLARE
    xt_data xmltype;
    v_ctx dbms_xmlgen.ctxHandle;
    rc_data sys_refcursor;
    v_file  UTL_FILE.file_type;

    BEGIN 
   -- v_file := UTL_FILE.fopen('MYXML', V_TABLE_NAME ||'.xml', 'A');       
     --  v_file := UTL_FILE.fopen('MYXML', V_TABLE_NAME || '.xml', 'A');


      v_file := UTL_FILE.fopen('MYXML', V_TABLE_NAME || 'Layout.xml', 'W');


    OPEN rc_data FOR 
    'select distinct column_name, data_type ,column_id
            from all_tab_columns
            where table_name ='||V_TABLE_NAME ||' order by column_id';

    v_ctx := dbms_xmlgen.newContext (rc_data);
    DBMS_XMLGEN.SETNULLHANDLING(v_ctx,null);

    DBMS_XMLGEN.setrowsettag(v_ctx, V_TABLE_NAME); 
   DBMS_XMLGEN.setrowtag(v_ctx, null);

     xt_data := dbms_xmlgen.getXMLType (v_ctx);
     dbms_xmlgen.closeContext (v_ctx);

    dbms_xslprocessor.clob2file(xt_data.getclobval( ), 'MYXML', V_TABLE_NAME || 'Layout.xml');
    v_FLAG := 1;


      EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
           DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM);
           dbms_xmlgen.closeContext (v_ctx);
            v_FLAG := 0;

      end ;

END table_str;
```

Please help here

Answer (score 1):

The query in the procedure isn't the same as the example you showed:

```
OPEN rc_data FOR 
'select distinct column_name, data_type ,column_id
        from all_tab_columns
        where table_name ='||V_TABLE_NAME ||' order by column_id';
```

... isn't enclosing the table name in quotes, and doesn't have a `upper` conversion, so if you're calling it as `table_str('Project', :flag)` then it won't find a match anyway. The query it runs at the moment would be:

```
select distinct column_name, data_type ,column_id from all_tab_columns
where table_name=Project order by column_id
```

... so it's using `Project` as an identifier (hence the error), not `'Project'` or more usefully `'PROJECT'` as a value.

You need:

```
OPEN rc_data FOR 
  'select distinct column_name, data_type ,column_id
    from all_tab_columns
    where table_name = ''' || UPPER(V_TABLE_NAME) || ''' order by column_id';
```

Or even better, with a bind variable:

```
OPEN rc_data FOR 
  'select distinct column_name, data_type ,column_id
    from all_tab_columns
    where table_name = :table_name order by column_id'
  USING UPPER(V_TABLE_NAME);
```

This assumes you haven't used quoted identifiers for your table names.